# How to read data from file till I encounter an empty line

Tags: java, string, file-read

Is there a way I can read multiple lines from a text file until I encounter an empty line?

For example my text file looks like this:

> text-text-text-text-text-text-text-text-text-text-text-text-text-text-text-text
>
> //This is empty line
>
> text2-tex2-text2-tex2-text2-tex2-text2-text2

Now, I want to input `text-text...` till the empty line into a string. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check below code, 1st i have read all the lines from text file, then i have check whether file contains any blank line or not, if it contains then i break the loop.

**A.text**

text-text-text-text-text-text-text-text-text-text-text-text-text-text-text-text

text2-tex2-text2-tex2-text2-tex2-text2-text2

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String args[]){
        try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("E:\\A.txt"))) {
            String line;
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                if(!line.isEmpty()){
                    System.out.println(line);
                } else {
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i am breaking the loop beacuse, to print 1st line as @Ajmal mentioned in his question to print, without use of break in loop it will exicute two text line.

Comment: yes you are right, that was my mistake. now i have changed the code, please check.

Comment: thanks guys! your code gave me an idea and I was able to figure it out.

Comment: @AjmalAli then you should accept the answer. (V symbol under answer score)